# The guy sits in in meetings or The guy sits in meetings.

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

Using:

*sitting in*; to attend as a guest.

How about:

The guy sits in in a meeting. vs The guy sits in a meeting.

Answer (score 2):

Neither will work.  Doubling the preposition

> The guy sits **in in** meetings

is too distracting, and

> The guy sits **in** a meeting

merely means that the guy attends the meeting, without the meaning that the he's a guest or outsider.  The solution is to use *in on*.  Here's an example from [*Cancer and Self-help: Bridging the Troubled Waters of Childhood Illness*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PXnUUbUZmhQC&pg=PA208&dq=%22sits%20in%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjetcXRyqvMAhWjnIMKHTPnAiwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22sits%20in%20on%22&f=false) by M A Chesler and B K Chesney:

> The parent-advocate sits **in on** all staff meetings, is part of
>   staff rounds, and also attends all group meetings.

Answer (score 0):

**Think of there being two verbs, which have slightly different meanings *to sit* and *to sit-in***.

I would definitely hyphenate *sit-in*, especially if I were to say *John sits-in in meetings*. Just to be even more clear to the listener/reader you could say or write *John sits-in at meetings*.